# Laravel: How to make a form with one action for each button

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have a form:

```
<form action="caption/{{$caption->id}}" method="delete">
    <p value='{{$caption->id}}'>{{$caption->content}}</p>
    <button type="submit">Delete caption</button>
    <button type="submit" formaction="<SEND A PUT TO CAPTION/CAPTION_ID>">Accept caption</button>
</form>
```

This form handles the deletion or approval of unapproved captions for pictures on my website. I have set up the form so that a `DELETE` is sent to `caption/caption_id` if `Delete button` is pressed.

Now, upon pressing the `Accept caption`-button, I want the `$caption->approved` field to be set to 1 (it is 0 by default). I have thought of how to do this, and my proposed solution (that I don't know how to implement) is this:

When pressing the accept, make the website send a `POST` request to `caption/caption_id`. The `POST` is then handled by the routing which sends it to a controller where I do what I need to do.

Questions:

1. How do I implement this solution?
2. If my solution is impractical or stupid, what is a better solution?

Thx

Comment: there are nothing called formaction , you will need to deal with that using javascript to control your DOM elements;

Comment: Could you explain how?

Comment: do you have a fair awareness of javascript ? do you use jquery ?

Comment: fair awareness of js. I know nothing about jquery.

Comment: does your script includes jquery source?

Comment: Yes, it does. It's in public/js/app.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you not send the request using two buttons, each in a form with the desired target action and method?

```
{{ $caption->content }}
<form action="caption/{{ $caption->id }}" method="POST">
    <button type="submit">Approve</button>
</form>
<form action="caption/{{ $caption->id }}" method="POST">
    <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE"/>
    <button type="submit">Reject</button>
</form>
```

This approach means you wouldn't need to use JavaScript.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't even think of that. Thx!

Comment: are you sure that it this works with you ? :) https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#form-method-spoofing !! as i know DELETE method is not for html forms ! `HTML forms do not support PUT, PATCH or DELETE actions. ...... `

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, @hassan - I have updated the answer.