# Laravel: Deleting something from database doesn't work

Tags: php, html, laravel, http

I have an app where I store captions for images. I have a delete function for captions that are routed like this:

```
Route::delete('caption/{id}', 'DetailController@deleteCaption');
```

to this function:

```
public function deleteCaption(Request $request, $id) {
    $caption = Caption::findOrFail($id);
    $caption->delete(); //doesn't delete permanently
}
```

unfortunately, as you can see in my comment, this function does not achieve its purpose of deleting the caption. It shows up again and again in the admin page upon pressing the delete button and reloading.

Admin page:

```
<p value='{{$caption->id}}'>{{$caption->content}}</p>
<form action="caption/{{$caption->id}}" method="delete">
    <button type="submit">Delete caption</button>
</form> 
<form action="caption/{{caption->id}}" method="post">
    <button type="submit">Accept caption</button>
</form>
```

What can I do about this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43016693/laravel-how-to-make-a-form-with-one-action-for-each-button ??

Comment: Don't see what you mean. This is an entirely different matter.

Comment: why at least you didn't put the solution which you accepted in the new question ?

Comment: My bad. Done....

Comment: Put your delete function inside a `dd()` and show us the result.
Do you have any Model Observer to this model that can be preventing the delete?

Comment: How do I put it inside a `dd`? And I don't know about the Model Observer but my guess is no.

Comment: Try to change to `Route::post('caption/{id}', 'DetailController@deleteCaption');` and add attribute to a form: `method="post"`. Another issue, just put in the controller 'dd('in the controller');' and you will see if it ever goes there.

Comment: Can't do that, because post is going to be used for altering the caption.

Comment: So maybe use `REST`? Route for delete would be `caption/{id}/delete`